# Lightning Web Components, Lightning-datatable / Lightning-tree-grid DOM traversal

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

With the API I managed to get `this.template.querySelector("lightning-tree-grid")`,
but getting to any inner element returns empty proxy object.
With the browser console I manage to find the required:

```
this.template.querySelector("lightning-tree-grid").shadowRoot.querySelector("lightning-datatable").shadowRoot.querySelector("[aria-level='2']")
```

But, unable to reach it in code.
Is it possible?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/documentation

Comment: not really, 
to find the the lightning-tree-grid is not a problem, the problem is to enter inside a component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this because of the [Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm):

> A component can only traverse the DOM and access elements created by a component in the same namespace. This behavior prevents the anti-pattern of reaching into DOM elements owned by components in another namespace.

All standard lightning components are outside your namespace.